# Javascript error code validation error border box hide if all input is true

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I code the different function for each inputs in javascript. Basically, I have the three types of errors. 
In the front of input Like Tick or Cross. Below the pargraph Like Plaese enter your name and last one is on the top of screen in the box. In the box all errors is included Like first name error and last name error.

===========================================================================

Please type your name

Please enter the title

## please enter the email and soo on...

I want to hide the top border box around the errors if all error is true.
Hope you got it what I mean:

```js
//Values--aditon

    var title=document.getElementById('title').value;
    var first_name=document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var lname=document.getElementById('last_name').value;
    var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var dob=document.getElementById('dob').value;
    var contact_number=document.getElementById('contact_number').value;

//End here
  function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
function testField(field) {
    var regExpr = new RegExp("^\d*\.?\d*$");
    if (!regExpr.test(field.value)) {
      // Case of error
      field.value = "";
    }
} 
function emailvalidate()
{
       var email=document.getElementById('email').value;

    if(validateEmail(email))
    {
        document.getElementById('email_success_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('email_error_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('top-email').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('below_error_email_msg').style.display='none';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {

        document.getElementById('below_error_email_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-email').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('email_success_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('email_error_msg').style.display='block';
        return false;
    }
}
function titlevalidation()
{
       var title=document.getElementById('title').value;
    if(title=='')
    {

        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-tag').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-title').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('title_below_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_success_msg').style.display='none';

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('top-title').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('title_below_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('below_error_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('title_below_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('below_success_msg').style.display='block';
        if (fnamevalidaton()==true) 
        {
            document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='none';
        }

    }
}
function fnamevalidaton()
{
    var first_name=document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    if(first_name=='')
    {

        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-tag').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fname_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-fname').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_fname_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fname_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('fname_success_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fname_error_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('top-fname').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('below_error_fname_msg').style.display='none';
        return true;
    }
}    
function lastnamevalidation()
{
    var lname=document.getElementById('last_name').value;
    if(lname=='')
    {

        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-tag').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-lname').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_lname_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('lname_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('lname_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('top-lname').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('lname_error_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('lname_success_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_lname_msg').style.display='none';
        return true;
    }
}
function dobvalidation()
{

    var dob1=document.getElementById('dob_input1').value;
    var dob2=document.getElementById('dob_input2').value;
    var dob3=document.getElementById('dob_input3').value;
    if(dob1=='' || dob2=='' || dob3=='')
    {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-dob').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_dob_msg').style.display='block';
      //  document.getElementById('dob_icon').style.marginLeft='-58px';
        document.getElementById('dob_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('top-dob').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dob_error_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('below_error_dob_msg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dob_success_msg').style.display='block';
       // document.getElementById('dob_icon').style.marginLeft='-58px';
        return true;
    }
}
function contactsvalidation()
{

    var contact_number=document.getElementById('contact_number').value;
    if(contact_number=='' || contact_number.length !=11)
    {
    document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('contact_error_msg').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('contact_success_msg').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('below_error_contact_msg').style.display='block';   
    document.getElementById('top-contact').style.display='block';
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('contact_error_msg').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('contact_success_msg').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('top-contact').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('below_error_contact_msg').style.display='none';
    return true;
    }
}
function validate()
{
    var fname = fnamevalidaton();
    var email=emailvalidate();
    var lname=lastnamevalidation();
    var title=titlevalidation();
    var dob=dobvalidation();
    var contact=contactsvalidation();
    return fname && email && lname && title && contact && dob;
}
```

```html
<form id="payForm" action="address-to-be-licensed.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return validate()">
                            <div id="headerErrorBox" class="info err" style="padding: 20px; padding-bottom: 30px; display: none;">
                                <p class="icon">
                                    <li id="top-tag" style="list-style: none; padding: 0 0 0.77em; display:block;">Something's not right. Please check those details again carefully. </li>
                                <ul class="errorDetails">
                                    <li style="display:none;" id="top-title">Please select your title</li>
                                    <li style="display: none;" id="top-fname">Please enter your first name</li>
                                    <li style="display: none;" id="top-lname">Please enter your last name</li>
                                    <li style="display: none;" id="top-email">Please enter your email address</li>
                                    <li style="display: none;" id="top-dob">Please enter your date of birth</li>
                                    <li style="display: none;" id="top-contact">Please enter your contact number</li></ul>
                            </div>

                            <p class="intro">Please complete all sections of this form, unless marked as optional.</p>

                            <div id="nameDetailsDiv1" class="frmRow contained name nonBusiness">

                                <div class="field_div">

                                    <label for="nameDetails_ddlTitle" id="nameDetails_lblTitle">Title</label>
                                    <select name="title" onchange="return titlevalidation()" id="title"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off">
                                        <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                                        <option value="Dame">Dame</option>
                                        <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                                        <option value="Lade">Lady</option>
                                        <option value="Lord">Lord</option>
                                        <option value="Professor">Professor</option>
                                        <option value="Reverend">Reverend</option>
                                        <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
                                        <option value="None">None</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id='below_error_msg' style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="below_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <p class="error_msg" id="title_below_msg" style="display: none;">Please select your title</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="field_div" >
                                    <label for="first_name" id="">First name</label>
                                    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="frmText" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="return fnamevalidaton()">
                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="fname_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id="fname_error_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <p class="error_msg" id="below_error_fname_msg" style="display: none;">Please enter your first name</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="field_div">
                                    <label for="last_name" id="">Last name</label>
                                    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="frmText validate" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur=" return lastnamevalidation()">
                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="lname_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id="lname_error_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <p class="error_msg" id="below_error_lname_msg" style="display: none;">Please enter your last name</p>
                                </div>

                                <p class="help">A TV Licence can only be held under a single name.</p>

                                <div class="field_div">
                                    <label for="email" id="">Email address</label>
                                    <input id="email" name="email" class="frmText validate" type="email" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="return emailvalidate()">
                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="email_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id="email_error_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <p class="error_msg" id="below_error_email_msg" style="display: none;">Please enter your email address</p>
                                </div>

                                <p class="helpEmail">
                                    We will only contact you with essential information about the TV Licence.
                                </p>

                                    <div class="field_div">
                                        <label for="dob" id="">Date of birth</label>

                                    <select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input1"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
                                        <option value="">DD</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                        <option value="13">13</option>
                                        <option value="14">14</option>
                                        <option value="15">15</option>
                                        <option value="16">16</option>
                                        <option value="17">17</option>
                                        <option value="18">18</option>
                                        <option value="19">19</option>
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="21">21</option>
                                        <option value="22">22</option>
                                        <option value="23">23</option>
                                        <option value="24">24</option>
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="26">26</option>
                                        <option value="27">27</option>
                                        <option value="28">28</option>
                                        <option value="29">29</option>
                                        <option value="30">30</option>
                                        <option value="31">31</option>
                                    </select>
                                        <select name="dob_mm" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input2"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25%">
                                         <option value="">MM</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <select name="dob_yy" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input3"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 33%;">
                                        <option value="">YYYY</option>
                                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
</select>
                                    </select>
                                        <!--
                                    <input id="dob_input" name="dob" class="" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" onblur="">
                                    <img class="dob" src="images/dob_icon.png" id="dob_icon" alt="" title="" style="margin-left: -30px; margin-top: 4px;">
                                -->
                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="dob_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id="dob_error_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <p class="error_msg" id="below_error_dob_msg" style="display: none;">Please enter your date of birth</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="field_div">
                                    <label for="contact_number" id="">Contact number</label>
                                    <input id="contact_number" name="contact_number" class="frmText validate" type="tel" pattern="/d" maxlength="11" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="return contactsvalidation()"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">

                                    <span class="inline1 successMessage" id="contact_success_msg" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="inline1 errorMessage" id="contact_error_msg" style="display: none;"></span>

                                    <p class="error_msg" id="below_error_contact_msg" style="display: none;">Please enter your contact number</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="helpEmail">
                                    We will only contact you with important information about your TV Licence and will not pass your details on to anyone else.

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="div">
                                <div class="btnGrp">
                                    <span class="arrowBtn">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" id="ctl00_Content_ctl02_btnSubmit">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This code work like. if user click on input `onblur` if input is blank cross and top bordered error show but if user correct the error top border don't disappear. If I disappear the top border in one validation then other error if come then it stay disappear. Hope you understand what I mean Thanks

More clear example on the website. check the validations after submit the blank and try to display none the top border.
Here is the website link: **http://blockcode.info/tv/**

Comment: Why dont use code snipper?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I did my best to explain my problem. so it may help you understand what I am looking for.

Comment: you're welcome! there is no element with id `dob`

Comment: I am not using it anywhere. you can ignore it. the main thing is how I disappear my top border if all inputs is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and you are validating things in every onblur of the inputs.
When validation is not passed you are showing the `headerErrorBox`, but when it is passed (returns true) you are not setting `headerErrorBox`'s display none.

**Update**:
I created `validations` object to save validation status and we can update UI every time when inputs' `onchange` or `onblur`:

```
 var validations = {
      title: false,
      email: false,
      first_name: false,
      last_name: false,
      dob: false,
      contact: false
    }
    function updateEmailMsg() {
      if (validations.email === true) {
        document.getElementById('email_success_msg').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('email_error_msg').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('top-email').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('below_error_email_msg').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('below_error_email_msg').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('top-email').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('email_success_msg').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('email_error_msg').style.display = 'block';
      }
      update();
    }
    function update() {

      if (validateAll()) {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display = 'none';
        return true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display = 'block';
        return false;
      }
    }

    function emailvalidate() {
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      validations.email = validateEmail(email);
      updateEmailMsg();
      return validations.email;
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e3xnc4h2/1/

**Note**: it is very not good experience actually. You better use arrays with loop, or try to use jquery, vuejs, ... for further development

Comment: definently it's not going to be worked because if I correct the one input the errors of other inputs in headererrorbox will disappear. I want the header error box dissapear when all inputs is ok.

Comment: any solution brother?

Comment: function update() {

  if (validateAll()) {
    document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display = 'none';
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  }
}

Comment: validateAll function is this function you mean?

function validate()
{
    var fname = fnamevalidaton();
    var email=emailvalidate();
    var lname=lastnamevalidation();
    var title=titlevalidation();
    var dob=dobvalidation();
    var contact=contactsvalidation();
    return fname && email && lname && title && contact && dob;
}

Comment: validateAll() is your old validate()